# Vector space, subspace, intersection, union

Tags: vector-spaces

If V : a vector space, why any intersection of subspace of V is a subspace of V? And Why any Union of subspace of V is not a subspace of V? I can't prove there...

Comment: First i understand that zero vector(the identity) is in the intersection of subspace, but i can't understand that why intersection of subspaces is closed by addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Well, the definition of subspace requires $0$ to be an element of the set. Therefore, $0$ is in every subspace, and in particular, in the intersection of two subspaces.

Comment: The question about the union of two vector spaces is either poorly translated or poorly phrased.  It is possible that the union of two subspaces is again a subspace, but it is not always true.  (*note the difference between "not always true" and "always not true"*)  There are examples where the union is.  There are also examples where the union is not.

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, then $0\in U$ and $0\in W$, hence $0\in U\cap W$. If $u,w\in U\cap W$, then $u,w\in U$ so $u+w\in U$, and $u,w\in W$ so $u+w\in W$, hence $u+w\in U\cap W$. If $c$ is a scalar and $u\in U\cap W$, then $cu\in U$ and $cu\in W$, hence $cu\in U\cap W$.

For a counterexample to show why the union of subspaces need not be a subspace, consider the span of two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: For a counterexample you could take y-axis and x-axis that are both subspaces but their union is obviously not closed under addition

Comment: @windircurse Yes, that would be the span of $(0,1)$ and the span of $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

We say a subset $S$ of a $\mathbb{k}$-vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if:

- $0_V \in S$
- $\alpha\cdot v \in S \ (\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{k}) \ (\forall v \in S)$
- $v + w \in S \ (\forall \ v,w \in S)$

We can sum this up by saying that S is **closed under linear combinations**, i.e. that

$$\alpha \cdot v + \beta\cdot w \in S \ (\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{k}) \ (\forall v,w \in S)$$

Now, if $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $V$, given any $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{k}$ and $v,w\in S\cap T$,

$$\alpha \cdot v + \beta\cdot w \in S \\ \alpha \cdot v + \beta\cdot w \in T$$

because both are subspaces, and therefore

$$\alpha \cdot v + \beta\cdot w \in S\cap T$$

so $S\cap T$ is a subspace of $V$.

As for $S \cup T$, what fails here is that if you take an element $s$ of $S$, and an element $t$ of $T$, they are both in $S\cup T$ but $s+t$ is not necessarily an element of $S\cup T$. In fact, you can prove that $S\cup T$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $S \subseteq T$ or $T \subseteq S$.